# ゲームエンジンGDevelopで指定回数後に処理を行いたい

Tags: javascript

#### GDevelopで指定回数後に処理を行う方法について

GDevelopを使用して簡単なゲームを作ろうとしていますが、分かりやすいイメージとして下記のようなことをやりたいです。

[ゲームの内容]

```
1） ターゲットに向かってダーツを投げる
2） ターゲットに2回命中すればゲームクリア
```

内容としては上記のような簡単なものなのですが、「2回命中すれば」の「2回」という指定回数に達した場合に、クリア状態にしたいのです。

ですが、現在この「2回」という指定回数のカウント方法が分からず詰まっている状態です。

現在の状態についてはエラーなど発生しているものはありません。

#### 現時点の状況

エラーはなく動いています。
ただし、2回という指定回数の処理を実現できていないため、現在は永遠とダーツを投げるという状況が続いている状態、つまりクリア状態にならない状況です。

#### 該当のソースコード

GDevelopでの実装のため、何を添付すべきか迷ったのですが、現在の状況が分かるようにGDevelopで作成しているものをキャプチャとして添付します。
https://gyazo.com/a7b54bf3bead93e61029d9484d46fb7a

#### 試したこと

ネットで検索しつつ考察中です。

#### 補足情報(言語/FW/ツール等のバージョンなど)

GDevelopをダウンロードしこれを使用して実装中。

※情報としてさらに必要なものがあれば示しますのでご連絡ください。
※https://teratail.com/questions/233440?modal=q-comp こちらにも同様の質問をしています。

Comment: 回答される方へ　https://teratail.com/questions/233440

Comment: 日本語でのサポートフォーラムが出来ているようで、そちらの方が早いのでは？ [ゲームアプリ制作ツール「GDevelop」の日本語サポートがスタート](https://www.4gamer.net/games/999/G999905/20191216096/), [日本語フォーラムをサポートするマイティークラフトです。](https://forum.gdevelop-app.com/t/topic/22121)

Comment: > kunifさん
そうですね、改めて調査してみます。